# how to set tab for auto indent after pressed enter in vscode rather than space

Tags: visual-studio-code

I must use a tab for indentation. I set Detect Indentation as true, and Insert Spaces as false. So that the tab will not be replaced with space. But auto indent after "enter" is still space, how can I fix it?

What I have done is on above.

Comment: Is the rest of your file indented with spaces? If so, that would probably be the reason, combined with your detect indentation = true.

Comment: "detect indentation = true" is already done